# How to get unique value from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, error-handling, group-by

I want to select distinct value in the query but it shows multiple values. I have 2 identical names in my name column. I think distinct is for unique value but I don't know what is happening.

Here is my query

```
string lakhas1 = "SELECT DISTINCT
NAME,EXPENSE,AMOUNT1,AMOUNT2,AMOUNT3,AMOUNT01,AMOUNT02,AMOUNT03 FROM
INCOME ORDER BY NAME";
DataTable dt1 = DataAccess.GetDataTable(lakhas1);
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` will be performed by all selected fields.

Comment: For getting distinct results you need to apply distinct only on name column

Comment: please see this https://imgur.com/GQIx2Ab

Comment: @TechNew, you need to post some sample data and expected result. Then people will be able to help.

Comment: https://imgur.com/oY6wOJL here is the sample data I hope anyone now can understand better

Comment: @TechNew all of those are unique. If you will tell Select NAME From Income - you'll receive 3 records

Comment: @TechNew https://www.w3resource.com/sql/select-statement/queries-with-distinct-multiple-columns.php

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your result set be distinct by `name`, you can use the `group by` keyword to group the records. When you do this, any other columns you want to select either have to be part of the group by (i.e. part of the key that makes the record distinct) or they have to be used in an aggregate function.

In this case, I assumed you want to sum the values from the records together. However, you could use `min()` or `max()` just the same.

```
select
    name,
    sum(expense) as expense,
    sum(amount1) as amount1,
    sum(amount2) as amount2,
    sum(amount3) as amount3,
    sum(amount01) as amount01,
    sum(amount02) as amount02,
    sum(amount03) as amount03
from dbo.income
group by name
order by name
```